# WPF uses and expected results of AccessText class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I was going through the class `AccessText` today. I couldn't identify exact use  and results of using this class.

> If you use `AccessText` with a Label and use `Target` property as a
>   `TextBox`, the `TextBox` will get focus when `access key` is pressed.see below code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=txtbox}">
        <AccessText>_first_second</AccessText>
    </Label>
    <TextBox Name="txtbox" Width="100" Height="50"/>
</StackPanel>
```

> If you use `AccessText` with a `Label` and use Target property as a
>   `Buton` , the `Button` `Click` event will get executed when `access
>   key` is pressed.

So my questions are

> ***1.what is the definitive behavior of `AccessText` Class? If I have to predict it's uses with other type of controls like `DataGrid`, `ComboBox`,
>   `RadioButton`? how can i be sure of expected result?***
>
> ***2.Why is this class derived from `FrameworkElement`? What applications does it have as a `FrameworkElement`? seems a bit more for
>   just specifying Accesskeys etc.***

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`AccessText` is a `FrameworkElement` that acts more or less like a special type of `TextBlock` that allows any keyboard character following a single underscore (`_`) to act as an access key.

For a given control, the behavior of associated access keys depends on its `OnAccessKey` method. `OnAccessKey` is a virtual method of `UIElement`, which provides the following definition:

```
protected virtual void OnAccessKey(AccessKeyEventArgs e)
{
    this.Focus();
}
```

So, any control that doesn't override the definition of `OnAccessKey` defined by `UIElement` will maintain the default behavior, which is for the control to be brought into focus when the access key is pressed.

`ButtonBase`, which `Button` inherits from, has the following definition for `OnAccessKey`:

```
protected override void OnAccessKey(AccessKeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsMultiple)
        base.OnAccessKey(e);
    else
        this.OnClick();
}
```

So the default behavior of `Button` and other controls that inherit from `ButtonBase` will be to bring the control into focus if `IsMultiple` is true, otherwise, it will raise the click event. (`IsMultiple` is true if an access key is associated with more than one `UIElement`.)

With this background in mind, here are the answers to your specific questions:

1. The definitive behavior of an `AccessText` element used as a control's `ContentPresenter` is to register the first letter following a single underscore with the `AccessKeyManager`, which will invoke the control's `OnAccessKey` method when the key is pressed. Knowing what this will do for a particular control requires knowing which definition of `OnAccessKey` is in force for that control. If there are no overrides in its inheritance chain, pressing the access key will bring the control into focus. If there is an override, the behavior will depend on the overriding method's definition. This can be determined via experimentation, reading relevant documentation, or examining the source code.
2. `AccessText` is a `FrameworkElement` for the same reasons that `TextBlock` is a `FrameworkElement`. It has a visual form and takes up space that the layout system needs to take into account when positioning other elements relative to it. Also, `FrameworkElements` allow for styling, and they possess their own `DataContext` property, which allows for binding scenarios that would otherwise not be possible. If `AccessText` were not a `FrameworkElement`, it would be unnecessarily limiting and prevent reasonable (though perhaps rare) use cases WPF developers may have.

**Edit**

Here's an example of a fancy power button that demonstrates the usefullness of `AccessText` being a `FrameworkElement`:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Width="150"
            Height="35"
            Command="{Binding PowerCommand}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Status" />
            <Rectangle Margin="5,2,0,0"
                       Width="10"
                       Height="10"
                       Fill="{Binding PowerFill}" />
            <AccessText Margin="25,0,0,0"
                        Text="{Binding PowerText}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

This results in (after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>):

[image]

After clicking the button, or pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, the view model would respond to the command by changing the `Text` and `Fill`, resulting in this:

[image]

Clicking or using the access key again would return to the first state.

Comment: @KyloRen, I attempted to flesh out answer #2 a bit more.

Comment: what does a WPF developer probably needs to bind in AccessText class?

Comment: *what does a WPF developer probably needs to bind in AccessText class?* Definitely the `Text` property, and possibly things like `Margin`, `Foreground`, `FontWeight`, and `FontStyle`. *I know i can set a layout for an access text class but is thre ever going to be a need?* I'll add an example. I do hear you that having a special `FrameworkElement` just for this purpose was an odd design choice. I'm not sure why they didn't just add a `RecognizesAccessKey` property to `TextBlock` and call it a day.